# Reading last 3 years transaction data and process only the updates after comparing with a tracker table in spark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Reading last 3 years transaction data and process only the updates after comparing with a tracker table in spark 2.4 .
I am running spark job for all even months and odd months in parallel .
e.g.

```py
eor_stage_df = eor_stage_df.filter((expr("cast(substring(order_date, 5, 2) as integer)") % 2) == check)
```

Distinct orders for all even and odd months is 900M, but i am constantly getting `ERROR server.TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result RpcResponse`

Could any one suggest best approach to it in pyspark?

Comment: Could you please add an example input/output and the complete code you tried?